# Рассчитать среднюю взвешенную

Tags: python, статистика

Необходимо рассчитать среднюю купюрность денег, выпущенных в обращение: для этого сначала нужно перемножить столбцы одной колонки на другую а потом поделить на сумму выпуска.... но ответ вышел не правильный...ошибка в почленном перемножении колонок...подскажите пожалуйста как исправить код чтобы значение из первой колонки * на значение из второй + значение из первой колонки вторая строка * на значение из второй колонки вторая строка и т.д. проще говоря 1 * 540+ 2 * 500+5 * 710 +10 * 610 и т.д.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('zad23.csv', delimiter=';')
import math
x = df['The_denomination_of_the_bill']*df['Outstanding']
n = df['The_denomination_of_the_bill'].sum()
Arithmetical_mean =  x / n
print(Arithmetical_mean)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы ведь только перемножаете, это `Series` из отдельных перемноженных значений получается. Вам нужно это всё просуммировать ещё, видимо, как-то так:

```
x = (df['The_denomination_of_the_bill']*df['Outstanding']).sum()
```